# how to re-organize the classes

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

There are $m$ Reception (R) classes in a school, each contains $n$ students, $m|n$. In September all $mn$ students will be in Primary 1 (P1).

In P1 there will still be $m$ classes each with $n$ students. However, to let students get to know more friends, the classes will be reorganized following rules:

- students will be re-orged so that each P1 class has $n/m$ students from each R class
- Each student could name $k$ R classmates (I.e. from his/her R class) that he/she would like to sit with in the P1 class. The re-org will try to fulfill as many as possible wishes, while fulfillment rate is named $F$.

e.g. There are $m=5$ R classes, each contains $n=15$ students, altogether there are 75 students. After re-org each P1 class has 3 "old friends" from each R class. Each student names $k=2$ "buddies", so there are $150$ wishes. If the re-org fulfilled 120 wishes, then fulfillment rate $F = 80\%$.

Question:

1. In which cases all wishes could be fulfilled?
2. Is there a good algorithm to re-org?
3. if the wishes are cast randomly, what is the expectation of $F$?

Comment: There seems to be some condition on the reorganization missing.  We can fulfill all the wishes if we reorganize into the same classes we have now.  I know you don't intend this to be acceptable, but I don't see where it's forbidden.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what that means.  Other than an example, is there a formal requirement?

Comment: Yes, I understand it now, thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, the $k$ friends that a student names are students in his present class that he would like to remain with, correct?  In that case, the various classes don't interfere with one another, and we just need to split each class into $m$ groups of $n/m$ students so the maximum number of wishes are fulfilled.

Comment: @saulspatz yes you are right. And I also updated the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Question $1$ only.

As @saulspatz pointed out, the various classes don't interfere with one another.  So we just need to consider a single class of $n$ students.  Represent them as an $n$-node directed graph $G$, where directed edge $(u,v)$ means student $u$ wishes to be in the same future class as student $v$.  Thus each node (student) $u$ has out-degree $k$.

Now consider the undirected graph $G'$ where edge $\{u,v\} \in G'$ iff $(u,v) \in G$ or $(v,u) \in G$.  Consider a connected component $C$.  Clearly, every wish of everyone in $C$ is respected iff every node (student) $c \in C$ is placed in the same future class.

Now consider all the connected components $C_1, C_2, ..., C_k$ and their sizes (no. of nodes/students) $|C_1|, |C_2|, ..., |C_k|$.  Every wish of everyone can be respected iff there is a way to partition these $k$ components into $m$ subsets $S_1, ..., S_m$ s.t. for every subset the sum of the component sizes $= n/m$, i.e.,

$$\forall i \in \{1, 2, ..., m\}: \sum_{C_j \in S_i} |C_j| = n/m$$

---

Remarks for Question $2$: we are trying to color the $n$ nodes of $G$ with $m$ colors, $n/m$ nodes per color, so as to minimize the number of directed edges with different colored endpoints.  The direction of the edge doesn't really matter[*] and we can equivalently consider the undirected graph as long as we allow $2$ edges between $u,v$ if each wishes for the other (or use edge weight $2$ and consider a weighted minimization). Sadly, I have not much idea how to solve this.

[*] A curious design choice since a 5-6-year-old kid who, *for the greater good*, ends up with none of his/her preferences will probably cry.  :)

Comment: For question 2, it’s NP hard

Comment: @athos - I would certainly guess that question 2 is NP-hard, but I don't know that for sure.  Do you have a reduction in mind?  Also, even if NP-hard, I thought you're also asking for a "good" algorithm i.e. a good approximation.  But even that, I have not much idea where to start.  For really small numbers like $3\times 5 = 15$ you can probably do it by hand...

Comment: @athos - In fact, come to think of it, even question 1 is a generalization of the subset-sum problem and already NP-hard.  :)  So this certainly implies question 2 is NP-hard.